# What is the range of a float represented as a Q16.16 integer?

Tags: fixed-point

When encoding a floating point number as a [fixed point integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) **Q16.16** with **int(number * 0x10000)**, what is the range of floating point that can be represented without loosing precision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range is 32767 to -32768 plus or minus the fractional part at maximum. So

32767 + 65535/65536 to - 32768 - 65535/65536.

However precision is a different thing to range. You've got up to 31 bits of precision.

Comment: I think you meant `65535/65536` instead of `65537/65535` (the latter is > 1) ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a two's complement 32-bit integer to represent a Q15.16, the range of the integer is `[2^31-1, -2^31]` or `[2147483647, -2147483648]` and the scale is `2^-16` or `1/65536`. Therefore the range of the fixed-point value is `[2147483647/65536, -2147483648/65536]` or approximately `[32767.99998, -32768]`.